# Error : The requested service 'Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext' has not been registered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, autofac

I am working in getting connectionstring with owin startup for tenant .I have MultiTenantOwinMiddleware to process Tenant.I have following code in my Startup class.
I am beginner with Owin.

```
builder.RegisterType<OwnerDbContext>()
            .AsSelf()
            .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof (string) && pi.Name == "ConnectionString",
                (pi, ctx) => GetTenantConnectionString(ctx)))
            .InstancePerRequest();

private static string GetTenantConnectionString(IComponentContext ctx)
    {
        var owinContext = ctx.Resolve<IOwinContext>();
        var tenant = owinContext.GetCurrentTenant<OwnerTenant>();
        return tenant != null ? tenant.ConnectionString : "XYZ";
    }
```

I am getting this error .
The requested service 'Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Edit

public static void ConfigureIoCContainer(this IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration config)
        {

```
        var container = RegisterInstances(); // Function for component registration

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);



        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(b => b.RegisterInstance(ctx).As<IOwinContext>()))
            {
                ctx.Set<ILifetimeScope>("idsrv:AutofacScope", scope);
                await next();
            }
        });

    }
```

Any any help would be appreciated.
Thank you very much

Comment: It's likely that you haven't correctly registered autofac as your dependency resolver with aspnet mvc. Assuming full .Net Framework (as opposed to dotnet core), have you done all of the following? https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#quick-start

Comment: ...especially this: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#owin-integration

Comment: Yes I have      DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container)); after registering instances.

Comment: Yes, but [there's more](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#owin-integration)... `app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container); app.UseAutofacMvc();` Did you do that?

Comment: Yes I have updated my question with that code

Comment: Why would setting `idsrv:AutofacScope` as a lifetime scope somehow replace the actual request lifetime scope? There's a lot missing here that you're not including.

Comment: @Travis Illig Could you please explain what part im missing?

Comment: @spender linked the docs above. Note the section about MVC not actually being in a full OWIN pipeline. Guessing you're hitting that... but, for example, I'm guessing from 'idsrv' in there that you're using IdentityServer somewhere. Where? There's more to this that is actually important. Help us understand why you thought setting `idsrv:AutofacScope` would help. Where'd you see that? That's not Autofac code, that's from... somewhere else. Where? (Update the question, don't just stick it in comments here.)